# Reloading a created float32 creates a tiled image

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I save numpy array as a raw to file (only has green channel so no RGB):

```
dtype_string = "float32"
>>> frames.shape
(40000L, 128L, 128L)

frames.astype(dtype_string).tofile(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/') + "aligned_" + str(ind) + ".raw")
```

This is what `plt.imshow(frames.astype(dtype_string)[400])` looks like:

[image]

You can download the raw I saved [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgz20duge0eem1f/aligned_0.raw?dl=0)

Now I just want to open the file I just saved as follows:

```
dat_type= "float32"

with open(g_file, "rb") as file:
    frames = np.fromfile(file, dtype=dat_type)
    total_number_of_frames = int(np.size(frames)/(width*height))
    print("n_frames: "+str(total_number_of_frames))
    frames = np.reshape(frames, (total_number_of_frames, width, height))
    frames = np.asarray(frames, dtype=dat_type)
```

But after this `plt.imshow(frames[400])` looks like this

[image]

Why am I getting a tiled image?

Comment: What is `frames.shape` before saving and what is it after reloading?

Comment: Which result of `plt.imshow(frames[400][:][:])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this answer as an extended comment, thank you. The example you gave us doesn't represent a MWE because we have no information about different values you use in your code.

I've stuck together this piece of code that mimics yours

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = "float32"
# a sinusoidal surface that rotates about the origin
x, y = np.linspace(0,10, 51), np.linspace(-5, 5, 51)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
a = np.linspace(-1, 1, 7)
z = np.sin(X[None,...]+a[...,None,None]*Y[None,...])

# reduce precision, plot
z = z.astype(dt)
plt.imshow(z[6]) ; plt.savefig('im6.png')

# output input
z.tofile('z.raw')
Z = np.fromfile('z.raw', dtype=dt)
Z = Z.reshape((7,51,51))

# plot
plt.imshow(Z[6]) ; plt.savefig('Im6.png')
```

and this is what I get from the shell prompt

```
$ md5sum Documents/tmp/?m6.png 
e4d9fc1358c85daec3f1680e5b9edcef  Documents/tmp/im6.png
e4d9fc1358c85daec3f1680e5b9edcef  Documents/tmp/Im6.png
$
```

i.e., the two files are identical. The main difference in codes lies in the use of the known values for the data array reshaping, so I *guess* that possibly it is the reshaping that went wrong.

Comment: You are wholly correct. Turned out to be a simple manner of width and height being the wrong values hich of course messes with the reshape